# How is an array organised after being spliced?

Tags: javascript

There is an array :

```
var tab = ["a","b","c","d"];
tab.splice(0,2);
```

What is the beginning index of the array after it has been spliced ? And how to know it ?

Comment: index never changes.its always zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After splicing an input array it returns new array that starts also wint index = 0.

You can check it i.e. with `for` loop:

```
var output = tab.splice(0,2);
for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
  console.log(i, output[i]);
}
```

Comment: So the starting index is always 0 ? And does it contain holes ? Or every indexes are contiguous ?

Comment: @pheromix it has no 'holes'. Please check my exaple `for`

Answer (score 2):

it's always 0. Even you splice, set null, undefined, etc....

I mean that if you set something such as tab[0] = null or tab[0] = undefined, the length of array is unchange, also the index. The length only change when you splice, remove item in array.
Example :

```
 var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
 console.log('Array length: %s, and index 0 value : %s ',array.length, array[0] );    //should be 8 and 1
 array[0] = undefined;
 console.log('Array length: %s, and index 0 value : %s ',array.length, array[0] );    //should be 8 and undefined
 array[0] = null;
 console.log('Array length: %s, and index 0 value : %s ',array.length, array[0] );    //should be 8 and null;
```

now add splice:

```
     var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
     console.log('Array length: %s, and index 0 value : %s ',array.length, array[0] );    //should be 8 and 1
     var arraySpliceLength = 2;
     array.splice(0,arraySpliceLength);
     console.log('Array length: %s, and index 0 value : %s ',array.length, array[0] );    //should be 6 and 3
```

The length changed, but the start index still at 0, and value = array[array.length - arraySpliceLength] = 2

Comment: can you expand on the part where you are setting null and undefined?

Comment: I mean that if you set something such as tab[0] = null or tab[0] = undefined, the length of array is unchange, also the index. is it what you're mention @Prabhu?

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf` method to see result.

```
var tab = ["a","b","c","d"];
tab.splice(0,2);
console.log(tab);
console.log(tab.indexOf("c"));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/saaa1gmd/)